# How to activate System Text-Replacement for Atom?

Tags: macos, keyboard

[Related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217378/is-it-possible-to-enable-osx-keyboard-text-substitution-in-more-apps)

I have configured some text replacements in my local machine, via `Preferences > Keyboard > Text`, including a lot of code shortcuts, including shortcuts for my own developed system urls, that are not *by-default* suggested by Atom, such as:

```
apj -> application/json
epc -> events/panels/criteria
hurl -> http://my.home.url/
```

But I can't get them to work in Atom. Any ideas? Is this already implemented in Atom?

Comment: As a side note: Atom is built on Electron which is built on Chromium; so it is possible the roots to the problem are the same as in the related question you linked to.

Comment: This question was made before I knew the concept of `snippets`. This is what solved my problem, it's awesome! http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/